# How to connect MYSQL database From a Admin system using Eclipse Juno?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

I have tried to create a Mysql connection between Server & Client System. My admin system ip address is (192.168.1.5). And I have a database "test". I downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.29 and added with Java Buildpath. 
The ScreenShot  is shown below:

[image]

Whenever i tried to test the connection, it shows the error like this..

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

```
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)

at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1129)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:358)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2320)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)

at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)

at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)

at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:214)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:73)

at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)

at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)

at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

```
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)

at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)

at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)

at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)

at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:308)

... 22 more
```

I have attached the Screenshot too..

Please help me to solve this issue.. Thanks in advace..
[image]

Comment: is the name of your database atrics or test ? You might want to look at your database name again in the connection url.

Comment: Can you ping your server from your client machine? Do you have any firewall settings in place that are blocking your server?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply.. sorry i mistaked there... my Ip address is 192.168.1.5 and db name is atrics. please help me to solve this

Comment: Nope... I can easily able to ping the server from the client system..

Comment: Anyone please try to help me to solve this one @Gyanapriya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your url to : jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/
And your database name to atrics instead of test.
HTH.
Check out http://itsolutionsforall.com/eclipse_sql.php

Comment: Do u know any MYSQL server-client connection tutorial in eclipse with screenshots?

Comment: Updated my answer with a tutorial link. HTH.

Comment: ya thats good one.. and i got solution. I updated that in my question.. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Updated Solution:

MySQL Connectivity between Client/Server Network using Eclipse:
•Download the Latest MySQL Software from the http://www.mysql.com/
•Install it to your Administrator System.
•Download the MySQL Connector from the following:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
(Only download the .zip or .rar file)
•Extract the file in a specific location. Example, 
D:\eclipse\mysql-connector-java-5.1.29
•Now Login to your Admin System and Open “MySQL Command Line Client” from the program list.
•Enter the password. (Which is you provided during the installation of MYSQL. By default “root”
•If you get any kind of error means you need to check the password or reinstall the MySQL.
•If you succeeded means, you will get the mysql command in the next line like this
mysql>
•   To view the current databases.
    mysql>show databases;
•To use a new database,

```
MySQL>use database_name;
```

example: 
mysql >use sample;

•To view the tables,

```
mysql>show tables;
```

Creating a New User:

•   Use the following query to create a new user.
    mysql>create user ‘JsAtrics’@’192.168.1.6’ identified by ’root’;
•   To give grant privileges,
    mysql>grant all privileges on *.* to ‘JsAtrics’@’192.168.1.6’;
•   Once you have finalized the permissions that you want to set up for your new users, always be sure to reload all the privileges.

```
 mysql>flush privileges;
 mysql>select user();

mysql>select current_user();
mysql> select host,user,password,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
```

•A list of users will be open. Check your username and check the privileges as “Y”.
•If it is “N”, execute the following,

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='JsAtrics';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'JsAtrics'@'192.168.1.6';
```

•Now again check the following:

```
mysql> select host,user,password,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
```

•If you see “Y” in privileges means that’s all. You finished.

Test Connection in Eclipse:
•Open Eclipse and Click WindowOpen Perspective  other  Database Development
•Now the Data Source Explorer open in the left or in the bottom.
•Right click on the Database Connections New  MySQLNext
•Now a new window will open.
•In the Connection Window Click New Driver (Which was placed in the right of Driver list)
•Select “MySQL JDBC Driver 5.1” and move to the “Jar list” tab and click clear all. And Click “Add Jar” and update the new connector which you downloaded early and extracted in the location D:\eclipse\mysql-connector-java-5.1.29
•After adding the jar file, move to properties tab. In that
Connection url: jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.5:3306/sample
Database Name: sample
Driver Class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Password: root
User ID : JsAtrics
•And Click “OK” Now Click “Save Password”.
•Now we can check the connection. So Click “Test Connection”
•It will displays a message “Ping Succeeded”.
•Click “Ok” and Click “Finish”.
•Now the database connected to your client system..!!!

Note: If you found any errors in this, read the above steps once again and follow the above steps once again.